# How to check for free cells in a line in the costmap?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, costmap, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
What I want to do is something similar to a raycast. From a specific position draw a line and get the list of all the free cells in that line. The line has a maximum length, but it has to stop if it reach an obstacle.
Is there an existing API for that? Or I need to implement it myself?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297035/how-to-check-for-free-cells-in-a-line-in-the-costmap?/) by [g.bardaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/28875/g.bardaro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2018-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the end I solved it by implementing a new layer on the costmap and using this:

http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/costmap_2d/html/classcostmap__2d_1_1Costmap2D.html#af1d619d9b49b6851cb0a33de4e39ec78

---

Originally posted by [g.bardaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/28875/g.bardaro/) with karma: 110 on 2018-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2